# Logout user from Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api

I use Facebook login for my Wordpress app (PHP SDK), which is installed on localhost.

After each registration via Facebook, I would need to logout the user from Facebook completely, so the next person that comes to the computer to register doesn't have access to his account.

I tried to call `$facebook->destroySession();`, which didn't work.

How can I logout user from FB completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this wount work. You need to use the [getLogoutUrl](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLogoutUrl/)

Something as

```
$params = array( 'next' => 'page after logout' );

$logouturl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl($params); // $params is optional.

<a href="<?php echo $logouturl; ?>"> Logout </a>
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to logout the user from my app, but not from Facebook. Ie., when I go back to my page and click login, I get automatically logged in again.

Comment: Hmm may be u need to try logout with JS SDK as FB.logout(function(){
       top.location.href = 'page after logout'
      }); https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/ but you need to make sure that the JS is loaded https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart

Comment: You saved my day! After spending 4 hours trying to make this work with the PHP SDK, with JS SDK it works just fine. Thanks!